# pnpm error Can't resolve 'decode-uri-component' in 'my-project/node_modules/query-string'

Tags: javascript, node.js, pnpm

I plan to use pnpm to start a project.

But when I run it, there's a error saying "Can't resolve 'decode-uri-component' in 'my-project/node_modules/query-string'".

It's strange that after using 'shamefully-hoist=true' in .npmrc , the problem is resolved.

how does is happen and how should i deal with it?

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEjmo.png)

[my childPackage's package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYA6T.png)

why this happend and how should i resole it ?